# Simple Calculator using radio button in php

Tags: php, radio-button, calculator

i made a simple calculator.But the problem is not radio buttons are not working properly to select the operation to be performed my code for input is as follow:

```
<form action="output.php" method="post" class="form">
    <label for="">Value 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="value1" placeholder="Enter 1st value">

    <br>
    <label for="">Value 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="value2" placeholder="Enter 2nd value">

    <h1>Select Operator </h1>
    <input type="radio" name="addition"       value="add">+
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="subtraction"    value="sub">-
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="multiplication" value="mul">*
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="division"       value="div">/
    <br>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Show Result">
</form>
```

and output php code is as follow:

```
<?php

    $value_1=$_POST['value1'];
    $value_2=$_POST['value2'];
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if($_POST['operation'] == add) {
            echo "$value_1 + $value_2";
        }else if($_POST['operation'] == sub){
            echo "$value_1 - $value_2";
        }else if($_POST['operation'] == mul){
            echo "$value_1 * $value_2";
        }else if($_POST['operation'] == div){
            echo "$value_1 / $value_2";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: have you defined `add`, `sub`, `mul` and `div` as constants?

Comment: yes i added them as constant

Comment: The reason your calculator is not working is simply because you are calling `if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )` but the actual `submit` button does not have a name...

Answer (score 1):

The radio buttons need to share the same name, only the value should change.

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="operation" value="add">+</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="operation" value="sub">-</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="operation" value="mul">*</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="operation" value="div">/</label>
```

Comment: thanks but none of the operations is working still

Answer (score 1):

The `submit` button has no name - so it will not appear in the POST array and the logic will never be processed. Rather than test for the presence ( or not ) of a button in the POST array you really should test for the actual form elements that you will use in your calculations.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>simple calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" class="form">

            <label>Value 1 <input type="text" name="value1" placeholder="Enter 1st value"></label>
            <label>Value 2<input type="text" name="value2" placeholder="Enter 2nd value"></label>
            

            <h1>Select Operator </h1>
            <input type="radio" name="operator" value="add">+
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="operator" value="sub">-
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="operator" value="mul">*
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="operator" value="div">/
            <br>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Show Result">
        </form>
        <?php

            /*
                Ensure that ALL post fields are set
            */
            if( isset(
                $_POST['value1'],
                $_POST['value2'],
                $_POST['operator']
            )) {
                /*
                    Assign POST values as variables.
                */
                $value_1=(int)$_POST['value1'];
                $value_2=(int)$_POST['value2'];     
                $operator=$_POST['operator'];
                
                /*
                    Perform the relevant calculation
                    and assign the correct symbol for display
                */
                switch( $operator ){
                    case 'add':$symbol='+';$res=$value_1 + $value_2;break;
                    case 'sub':$symbol='-';$res=$value_1 - $value_2;break;
                    case 'mul':$symbol='*';$res=$value_1 * $value_2;break;
                    case 'div':$symbol='/';$res=$value_1 / $value_2;break;
                }
                
                /*
                    print the sum and result
                */
                printf(
                    '%d %s %s=%d',
                    $value_1,
                    $symbol,
                    $value_2,
                    $res
                );
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "add" in C:\xampp\htdocs\ez\output.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ez\output.php on line 10

Comment: The error must be in your translation/adaptation of the above - there are no errors in the example I have

Comment: thanks a lot, I got a fix to forget to use double quotation here ="add" now calculator is working fine